# How to set the server and port in the Visual Studio Django Web Project template

Tags: django, visual-studio

I created a Django web project in Visual Studio 2017. In the context menu of the project icon in the Solution Explorer view, in the "Python" entry,  I can select, among other actions, "Start server" and "Start debug server". A cmd window opens and shows that it is sourcing the correct config settings and then attempts to start the server at localhost, port 8000. Here is where it fails on my machine since that port is taken. **How do change that port (and server address) for using the context menu**? (I do know how to change it for starting runserver on the command line or via the Debug configuration.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Visual Studio check for **Solution Properties** then **Debug Tab**

In the **Run** Section you can change `Launch URL` with the `IP value` and `port`

e.g: `http//localhost:8001`

Comment: For me it was on the project-level, not the solution-level.

Answer (score 0):

This will just change the browser url launched , The solution of this is to change port number in the Project Settings/port number field and edit debug/run server commands in settings page as under:

```
runserver --settings $(DjangoSettingsModule) [ADD YOUR IP HERE:]%SERVER_PORT% $(CommandLineArguments)
```